# Data.Iteration.Element (aka UInt 8) cannot be cast as unrelated Type

Tags: json, dictionary, swift3

I am having trouble in my codes, when trying to parse JSON data from an API from internet (this is the code part)

```
if let jsonDataArray = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: [])
                        {

                            print(jsonDataArray)

                            var allStops = [busStops]()

                            for eachData in jsonDataArray (this is where the Type 'Any' error is)
                            {

                                if let jsonDataDictionary = eachData as? [String : AnyObject]
                                {

                                    let eachStop = busStops(jsonDataDictiony: jsonDataDictionary)

                                }

                            }

                        }
```

I get this error (eachData cannot be casted to [String : AnyObject]

```
Cast from 'Data.Iterator.Element' (aka 'UInt8') to unrelated type '[String : AnyObject]' always fails
```

Edit: Changed JSONSerialization.data(...) with JSONSerialization.WithObject(...) just as mentioned and throws out error

```
Type 'Any' doesn't conform to protocol 'Sequence'
```

Comment: I guess you want to decode JSON data into Swift (Objective-C) object, in such cases, you need to use `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:)` rather than `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:options:)`. Replace the first method, and then fix other parts according to the change.

Comment: Hi @OOPer I tried your method, but it throws an error "type 'Any' doesn't conform to protocol Sequence, will update my question. Thanks for replying though